# Move table row data to another row in html

Tags: javascript, html

I want to transfer the complete table row data with id="table_data", to another row with id="table_data_two". On click of button

```
<table border="">
            <tr id="table_data">
                <td>this data</td>
                <td>this also</td>
                <td>this too</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
<table border="">
            <tr id="table_data_two">
             </tr>
        </table>
<button>click me</button>
```

Comment: Please don't shout in the title of your question (don't use all capital letters)...

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you already tried yourself to do this? Please review [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to research your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, so we can help.

Comment: There are a bunch of answers to this question on SO and the internet. Just search for "javascript move a dom element".

Answer (score 0):

The following is a very dirty hack to do what you're asking about, but I don't think it's the best approach to the situation.

I believe the issue isn't "copy HTML form A to B", but a more complex issue that produced the HTML you want to change.

Anyway, here's the hack:

```
document.getElementById("table_data").innerHTML = 
    document.getElementById("table_data_two").innerHTML;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the innerHTML and copy it to the other table,
just give ad id "btn" to your button.
but on the second click will copy the empty innerHTML, si I added a check.
http://jsbin.com/lakajipeki/edit?html,js,output

```
document.getElementById("btn").addEventListener("click", function(){
    var rows = document.getElementById("table_data").innerHTML;
    if(rows === ""){return}
    document.getElementById("table_data").innerHTML = ""
    document.getElementById("table_data_two").innerHTML = rows
});
```